# Tool for displaying text/code ratio in html

Tags: html, optimization

I am looking for a firefox/firebug plugin (or any OFFLINE tool is OK) to display the ratio of real text/markup.

*There are online tools, like http://www.seochat.com/seo-tools/code-to-text-ratio/ and this Firefox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/150366/ (this is online too).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small script in PHP, the main part is:

```
$toparse = "htmltext";
$toparse = preg_replace('/(<script.*?>.*?<\/script>|<style.*?>.*?<\/style>|<.*?>|\r|\n|\t)/ms', '', $toparse);  
$toparse = preg_replace('/ +/ms', ' ', $toparse);  
$textlen = strlen($toparse);
```

There are some calculations after this.
That regex can be shorter, but it works. The only requirement is paired `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ (URL=www.google.com; echo "scale=2;"`lynx -nolist -dump $URL | wc -c`/`curl -silent $URL | wc -c` | bc)
.06
```

Though the nice HTML rendering of `input`s in `links` skews the stats a bit.

Comment: Some less painful (1 click) would be better. Did I say I am using Windows? :)